# When Serialize and Deserialize call in passport js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have to know when Serialize and Deserialize called, for testing I have put `alert(user.id)` but no action happened.

I have some queries:

- From where `user` object has received in `passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){...`
- What role play `process.nextTick()` here
- How to call callback function i.e, `function(req, email, password, done)`, if I send multiple form values e.g(name, email, password, address, mobile).

Here is the code:-

```
 //config/passport.js

var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User            = require('../app/models/user');

module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        alert(user.id);//// Here is my testing alert
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });


passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true 
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
       process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {

            if (err)
                return done(err);

            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } else {
                var newUser            = new User();
                newUser.local.email    = email;
                newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }

        });    

        });

    }));
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Based on my knowledge of using Passport.js for a project, I will try to answer as much as I can.

First of all, there is nothing (function) like `alert()` in nodejs, so you would have to rename your `alert(...)` which is a browser thing, to something like `console.log(...)`

I cannot see your app.js file so, I will go ahead and try to answer your queries based on my experience of using passportjs.

Assuming that you have following in your `app.js` (order is important, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781294/passport-js-passport-initialize-middleware-not-in-use))

```
var passport = require('passport');
// express-session configs here
// following is invoked on each request.
app.use(passport.initialize());
```

`passport.initialize()` and `passport.session()` are invoked on each request and they are the ones that cause `serializeUser` to load the user id to `req.user` if a serialized user is found in the server (when using mongodb, if the user exist in mongodb).

`passport.session()` calls `deserializeUser` on each request, which queries the mongodb using the `user._id` that was initially loaded to `req.user` by `serializeUser` and stores the more information about user in the `req.user`.

`process.nextTick()` defers the execution of the callback until the next pass around the event loop. Database querying is sync in nature and `process.nextTick()` make it asynchronous. There is lots of tutorials about this, Google it.

As mentioned earlier, `app.use(passport.session())` runs `deserializeUser` on each request (basically every request - if you list your express static path configs after `passport.session()` then even for requests that load static files). In my case, I needed authentication on specific routes and I wanted to do the authentication, `deserializeUser` etc to occur only when the user accesses a secure path hence, I had to put a condition to invoke `passport.session()` only when the path matched certain pattern as follow:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(req.url.match('/xxxx/secure'))
    passport.session()(req, res, next)
  else
    next(); // do not invoke passport
});
```

Replacing `app.use(passport.session())` with above helped. Now only when the user access secure paths, the passport process is invoked including `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser`. I am not sure if above is the perfect solution but, it greatly helps in reducing the amount of unnecessary querying of mongodb for user (deserializeUser).

Not sure what you are asking in your last point. There are quite a few tutorials that shows how to implement passportjs for local as well as social auth. You should have a look around.

**MORE READING**

For more interesting facts on how the `session` is loaded with user, read my answer in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359295/how-does-passport-js-stores-user-object-in-session/35360972#35360972). It describes what `Express` does? what `PassportJS` does? and you will understand the the workflow easily (documentation makes it confusing and ambiguous).

Comment: I have a question, when you say : "passport.initialize() and passport.session()... they are the ones that cause serializeUser to load the **user id to req.user if a serialized user is found in the server (when using mongodb, if the user exist in mongodb). ** " Where does the user id come from? and when you say "if the user exist in mongodb", Does it automatically look in the User model?

Comment: Can your  code refactor as `if(req.url.match('/xxx')) passport.session(); next();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57290983/1503130 , can you please check this thread, I am banging my head on the internet but couldn't find the exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your 3rd point is

How to call callback function

```
function(req, email, password, done), if send multiple form values e.g(name,email,password,address,mobile).
```

As per my understanding,4th argument takes as a call back function.you can not use like and throw error

```
 function(req, email, password, mobile, address, done)
```

Answer (score -1):

Serialization happens when you authenticate a user:

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local'),
        function(req, res) {
        // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
        // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
        res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
});
```

Please find this code in you project and check if it looks like above and not like below:

```
passport.authenticate('local', { session: false })
```

Also please check does your project use sessions. See [Sessions](http://passportjs.org/docs/configure) in official docs.