# what does req.login do in passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using multiple passport stratergy across my app.

Now, since I am using multiple passport strategy to connect (and not to just sign-in), I decided to Google things on how to do it.

This is where I stumbled upon this code

```
 passport.authenticate('meetup', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect(process.env.CLIENT_ADDRESS); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.redirect(process.env.CLIENT_ADDRESS);
          });
```

Here I am unable to comprehend what is happening, like for first question, what is  `if (!user)`, Does it mean `req.user`

Second, there is  `req.logIn()`

According to [passport docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/),

> Passport exposes a login() function on req (also aliased as logIn())
>   that can be used to establish a login session.

and

> When the login operation completes, user will be assigned to req.user.

Then what is the difference between using **serializer/deserializer** when compared with **req.login?**

Also in the callback, we can always do this

```
  passReqToCallback: true
  }, (req, accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, cb) => {
```

to get **`req`**

To summarize can someone please help me comprehend the above code snippet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does passport js stores user object in session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359295/how-does-passport-js-stores-user-object-in-session)

Comment: Check out this description of the control flow: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/208#issuecomment-113445331

Answer (score 6):

At a high level Passport.js is a middleware that "serializes" a user identity in a request/response header (usually a session cookie). This serializing step means that it's taking the login information that identifies a user and produces a new object that represents the user. Think of this object as a key  card that only Passport will know how to interpret.

When a user makes additional API requests they pass that same identification header back. Passport auths the request by "deserializing" it to identify what user is making that request.

`req.login()` is the magic that is generating a session for a user. This session represents how long a login is good for without having to re-authenticate.

Let's take a look at the beginning of your snippet:

```
 passport.authenticate('meetup', (err, user, info) => {
   ...
   if (!user) { return...
```

In this snippet, passport is being set up as middleware. When a request comes through, passport behind the scenes has already interpreted the request header by deserializing the cookie and determines if it represents a user. If there is not a user or the request header does not represent a user, the request is not authorized.

Answer (score 4):

---

### req.login aliased as req.logIn

1. Passport exposes a login() function on req (also aliased as logIn()) that can be used to establish a login 
   session.
2. When the login operation completes, user will be assigned to req.user
3. Note: passport.authenticate() middleware invokes req.login() automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Use a lower version of passport for this feature v0.4.1

You can install this with

```
npm install passport@^0.4.1
```

Your `req.login` function should work with that version.

Answer (score -1):

I still have this problem until today
My problem is that passport needs to write user to the session store before it can set Set-Cookie and this process is asynchronous.

this is my solution

```js
const { promise, resolve, reject } = deferred();
req.login(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(user);
      }
    });
    await promise;
    const url = this.urlService.getRedirectUrl();
    return redirect(url);
```