# module priority cannot solve my 'passport.initialize() middleware not in use'

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bkfd2Password = require('pbkdf2-password');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var hasher = bkfd2Password();

var conn = require('../db/db_con')();
var config = require('../db/db_selector');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(session({
    secret: '432984252#!%#!$',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MySQLStore(config.dbConfig, conn)
}));

var router = express.Router();
```

:: this is head of 'login.js',
Node, express, passport, session, mysql...

For solving middle-ware hell, 
I took the solutions by stackoverflow, about 100~200 questions and answers, but failed.

And when I executed login process, the error is from routes/signup.js:70:25,
the part is,

```
console.log('LocalStrategy', account);
done(null, account);
```

I can show localstrategy and account, 
and done() func makes hell.
signup.js is similar to login.js.

Comment: please add your error details or stack trace.

Comment: Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (App/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:46:34)
    at Strategy.strategy.success (App/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:248:13)
    at verified (App/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:83:10)
    at App/routes/signup.js:70:25
    at AsyncWrap.<anonymous> (App/node_modules/pbkdf2-password/pbkdf2-password.js:150:7)
    at AsyncWrap.wrap.ondone (internal/crypto/pbkdf2.js:36:48)

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781294/passport-js-passport-initialize-middleware-not-in-use

Comment: The solution is, cookieParser->session->pass.init->pass.sesssion->router. upper login.js is not match, but signup.js is 100% same. But there is error.. I contact more than 200 questions and answers as I referred.. However, it is not resolved yet. anyway thanks!